# jQuery fade elements on click

Tags: jquery

I'm a noobie in the programming field and I've been messing around with jQuery and I was wondering how can I achieve the following:

Please take a look so you can understand better what I want to reach
This is what I've come up with: http://jsfiddle.net/Whok7345/2wddabnx/ (snippet below)

```js
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $("#menu").accordion({
        collapsible: true,
        active: false
    });
    $("#stuff_header").click(function (e) {
        $("#stuff_header_1").fadeOut("slow");
        $("#stuff_header_2").fadeOut("slow");
        $("#stuff_header").click(function (e) {
            $("#stuff_header_1").fadeIn("slow");
            $("#stuff_header_2").fadeIn("slow");
        });
    });

});
```

```html
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="menu">
    
<h4 id="stuff_header">stuff</h4>

    <ul id="ul_header">
        <li>stuff1</li>
        <li>stuff2</li>
        <li>stuff3</li>
        <li>stuff4</li>
        <li>stuff5</li>
        <li>stuff6</li>
    </ul>
    
<h4 id="stuff_header_1">more stuff</h4>

    <ul id="ul_header">
        <li>stuff1</li>
        <li>stuff2</li>
        <li>stuff3</li>
        <li>stuff4</li>
        <li>stuff5</li>
        <li>stuff6</li>
    </ul>
    
<h4 id="stuff_header_2">JavaScript</h4>

    <ul id="ul_header">
        <li>stuff1</li>
        <li>stuff2</li>
        <li>stuff3</li>
        <li>stuff4</li>
        <li>stuff5</li>
        <li>stuff6</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Click on "stuff" and you'll notice that the other two headers fade out, click on it again and the other headers fade in.

Everything good so far but when I try to do it again the two other headers fade in and out and the effect seen in as soon as the page loads doesn't happen anymore.

Can somebody help me to get that effect anytime I want?

Comment: Did you see a warning message when you tried to add a fiddle link? SO policy is: No code in the post, no fiddle link either. Please add the code to the post too.

Comment: There is a reason why you can not post links to code. using ++ to get around it is bad.

Comment: Please use the **integrated snippet** function instead of external services.

Comment: - sigh - tried my best to edit the question, but what you ask is not really the problem in your code. Please review it and try making it more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think I understood what you want.

Your error comes from your strange callback function, where you define another callback function (you actually create a loop).

Here is a corrected one, that should do the trick (see snippet)

```js
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $("#menu").accordion({
        collapsible: true,
        active: false
    });

    $("#stuff_header").click(function (e) {
        // check if stuff_header_1 is visible or not, and do the wanted transition
        if ($("#stuff_header_1").is(':visible')) { 
            $("#stuff_header_1").fadeOut("slow");
        } else {
            $("#stuff_header_1").fadeIn("slow");
        }

        if ($("#stuff_header_2").is(':visible')) {
            $("#stuff_header_2").fadeOut("slow");
        } else {
            $("#stuff_header_2").fadeIn("slow");
        }
    });


});
```

```html
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="menu">
    
<h4 id="stuff_header">stuff</h4>

    <ul id="ul_header">
        <li>stuff1</li>
        <li>stuff2</li>
        <li>stuff3</li>
        <li>stuff4</li>
        <li>stuff5</li>
        <li>stuff6</li>
    </ul>
    
<h4 id="stuff_header_1">more stuff</h4>

    <ul id="ul_header">
        <li>stuff1</li>
        <li>stuff2</li>
        <li>stuff3</li>
        <li>stuff4</li>
        <li>stuff5</li>
        <li>stuff6</li>
    </ul>
    
<h4 id="stuff_header_2">JavaScript</h4>

    <ul id="ul_header">
        <li>stuff1</li>
        <li>stuff2</li>
        <li>stuff3</li>
        <li>stuff4</li>
        <li>stuff5</li>
        <li>stuff6</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

*Note : I feel there should be a proper way to code that*